# Get output from array in Ada

Tags: ada

I want to print array data user input.
But it give me error. I need to get input from user and store in the array. After this i want to print it also count each duplicate word.

```
with Ada.Text_IO;
use Ada.Text_IO;    

procedure Main is
   type String_Val is array (1 .. 100) of Character;
   type Int_Val is array (1 .. 100) of Integer;
   Data : String_Val;
begin
   Put_Line ("Please enter values (use space as seperator)");
   for I in 1..String_Val'Length loop
      Data(I) := Character'Value(Get_Line);
   end loop;
   for I in String_Val'Range loop
      Put (String_Val (Data));
   end loop;
end Main;
```

Comment: A character is not a word. Your description indicates identifying and counting duplicate words but your String_Val type contains characters. The Ada Get_Line function returns a string, not a character. Study strings and characters a bit more.

Comment: In my opinion this question should have been closed, not answered. It shows no research effort. It’s not consistent, as Jim points out, so we don’t really know what OP’s trying to do. And "it give me error" - come on, OP, what was the error? (I can see two straight off, but the chances of this being an accurate copy of OP’s actual code are remote).

Comment: While I agree that the question should have been closed, I only see one error. If I change the Put to 'Put (Data (I) );` it works fine on appropriate input. The prompt is misleading, but I don't consider that an error.

Comment: `Data(I) := Character'Value(Get_Line);` .. not sure what an appropriate input would be for this?

Comment: Lines that look like the result of Character'Image, of course.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The following program reads a string as input, tallies the occurrences of characters in the string and outputs both the input string and the occurrences of each character in the input string.

```ada
with Ada.Text_IO; use Ada.Text_IO;

procedure Main is
   type Character_Counts is array (Character) of Natural;
   Input  : String (1 .. 100); -- String is an array of Character;
   Counts : Character_Counts := (Others => 0);
   Length : Natural;
begin
   Put_Line("Enter a string:");
   Get_Line(Item => Input,
            Last => Length);
   Put_Line ("You entered:");
   -- output the data entered by the user
   Put_Line(Input(1..Length));
   
   -- Count character occurrences in the string
   for I in 1 .. Length loop
      Counts(Input(I)) := Counts(Input(I)) + 1;
   end loop;
   
   -- output counts of characters in the string
   for C in Counts'Range loop
      if Counts(C) > 0 then
         Put_Line(Character'Image(C) & " : " & Counts(C)'Image);
      end if;
   end loop;
   
end Main;
```

Type Character_Counts is an array of Natural indexed by all the values of type Character. Natural is a pre-defined subtype of integer with a minimum value of 0. The variable Counts is an instance of Character_Counts with all its elements initialized to 0.

The Get_Line procedure returns the string you passed in, filled with characters up to the length of the string or the number of characters entered. The variable Length contains the number of characters entered by the user.

When counting the occurrences of the characters in the string the each character of the string is used as an index into the variable Counts, and the corresponding element in Counts is incremented.

A sample execution of this program is:

```
Enter a string:
This is a test.
You entered:
This is a test.
' ' :  3
'.' :  1
'T' :  1
'a' :  1
'e' :  1
'h' :  1
'i' :  2
's' :  3
't' :  2
```